# NameError: name 'ocjena' is not defined

Tags: python

```
broj = 20
bodovi = int(input('Upisite broj bodova: '))
konacnica = (bodovi/20)*100

o1 = range(0, 50);
o2 = range(51, 66);
o3 = range(67, 77);
o4 = range(78, 89);
o5 = range(90, 100);

if(bodovi == o1):
    ocjena = ("1")
elif(bodovi == o2):
    ocjena = ("2")
elif(bodovi == o3):
    ocjena = ("3")
elif(bodovi == o4):
    ocjena = ("4")
elif(bodovi == o5):
    ocjena = ("5")

print (bodovi, "bodova je za ocjenu", ocjena)
```

i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\pajton.py", line 22, in <module>
    print (bodovi, "bodova je za ocjenu", ocjena)
NameError: name 'ocjena' is not defined
```

so, what I actually want is check is variable "bodovi" in range of o1, o2, o3, o4 or o5..

Answer (score 5):

You must replace your `==` with `in` for example:

```
if bodovi in o1:
```